# How to add Scalar to Mat by mask?

Tags: opencv

How to add Scalar to Mat only where mask>0?

this code don't work as expected, area where mask>0 is img.value+scalar but where mask=0 us 0, but I expected img.value.

```
 add(image,Scalar(0,0,80),dst, mask);
```

code that work as I expect is

```
Mat dst;
image.copyTo(dst,mask);
add(dst,Scalar(0,0,80),dst, mask);
dst.copyTo(image,mask);
dst= image;
```

but it's not very clear, is there any simpler variant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `dst` image is uninitialized, the values outside the mask are set to `0`.

You get the expected behavior if you use as destination an initialized matrix. It can be your source matrix;

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Initial image
    Mat3b image(10, 10, Vec3b(0,2,0));

    // Mask
    Mat1b mask(10,10, uchar(0));
    rectangle(mask, Rect(0,0,3,4), Scalar(255), CV_FILLED);

    add(image, Scalar(0, 0, 3), image, mask);

    return 0;
}
```

Or if you need the source matrix to remain unchanged, you can simply clone the source image to the destination image before the `add`, like:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Initial image
    Mat3b image(10, 10, Vec3b(0,2,0));

    // Mask
    Mat1b mask(10,10, uchar(0));
    rectangle(mask, Rect(0,0,3,4), Scalar(255), CV_FILLED);

    Mat3b dst = image.clone();
    add(image, Scalar(0, 0, 3), dst, mask);

    return 0;
}
```